pythonでsqlite3がimportできない
Python3.12でのsqlite3のimportでエラーが出ます。
Python 3.12.4 (main, Jun 17 2024, 16:34:29) [GCC 13.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/desert/.pyenv/versions/3.12.4/lib/python3.12/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/home/desert/.pyenv/versions/3.12.4/lib/python3.12/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'

いろいろ試したところ、pysqlite3-binaryをインストールしてからのimport pysqlite3はうまくいったんですが、使いたいライブラリがimport sqlite3としているのでそれも難しいです。
まず、NoNameErrorじゃなくてModuleNotFoundが出ているのがよくわかりません。
環境

WSL2 on Ubuntu 24.04
Python 3.12.4

追記
❯ apt list | grep libpython3.12-stdli

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libpython3.12-stdlib/noble,now 3.12.3-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

❯ apt show libpython3.12-stdlib
Package: libpython3.12-stdlib
Version: 3.12.3-1
Priority: important
Section: python
Source: python3.12
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 9228 kB
Depends: libpython3.12-minimal (= 3.12.3-1), media-types | mime-support, netbase, tzdata, libbz2-1.0, libc6 (>= 2.38), libcrypt1 (>= 1:4.1.0), libdb5.3t64, libffi8 (>= 3.4), liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614), libncursesw6 (>= 6.1), libreadline8t64 (>= 7.0~beta), libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.36.0), libtinfo6 (>= 6)
Breaks: libpython3.12-testsuite (<< 3.12.0-3~), python3-gdbm (<< 3.9.9-1~)
Replaces: libpython3.12-testsuite (<< 3.12.0-3~), python3-gdbm (<< 3.9.9-1~)
Task: cloud-minimal, minimal, server-minimal
Download-Size: 2067 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
Description: Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.12)
 Python is a high-level, interactive, object-oriented language. Its 3.12 version
 includes an extensive class library with lots of goodies for
 network programming, system administration, sounds and graphics.
 .
 This package contains Python 3.12's standard library. It is normally not
 used on its own, but as a dependency of python3.12.

存在することはするみたいです。
❯ sudo apt update; sudo apt install build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev curl git \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev

結果は同じでした。。。
❯ apt show sqlite3
Package: sqlite3
Version: 3.45.1-1ubuntu2
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) <gcs@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 583 kB
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34), libreadline8 (>= 6.0), libsqlite3-0 (= 3.45.1-1ubuntu2), zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0)
Suggests: sqlite3-doc
Homepage: https://www.sqlite.org/
Download-Size: 144 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
Description: Command line interface for SQLite 3
 SQLite is a C library that implements an SQL database engine.
 Programs that link with the SQLite library can have SQL database
 access without running a separate RDBMS process.

❯ apt show libsqlite3-dev
Package: libsqlite3-dev
Version: 3.45.1-1ubuntu2
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Source: sqlite3
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Laszlo Boszormenyi (GCS) <gcs@debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 3401 kB
Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.45.1-1ubuntu2), libc-dev
Suggests: sqlite3-doc
Homepage: https://www.sqlite.org/
Download-Size: 911 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
Description: SQLite 3 development files
 SQLite is a C library that implements an SQL database engine.
 Programs that link with the SQLite library can have SQL database
 access without running a separate RDBMS process.
 .
 This package contains the development files (headers, static libraries)


この辺の記事が参考になるかも。ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3' Error when try to import sqlite3 and Django in Ubuntu, Pyenv No Module Named '_Sqlite3', Question with sqlite3 #678

ubuntuであれば、libpython3.12-stdlibというパッケージに入っているようなので、インストールされているか確認してください。(でも、インストールされていないとは思えないんですけどね…) https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble/amd64/libpython3.12-stdlib/filelist

あぁ、pyenvを使っているのですね。であればkunifさんのおっしゃるとおりかと。

pythonの版数が古いですがこんな記事が参考になるかも。【pyenv】pythonビルド後のModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3', pyenvを使ってpythonをインストールするときに出たエラー達

pyenv install 3.12.4 やり直してますか? > "結果は同じでした。。。"

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment
にpyenvを使う時の必須パッケージがあります
Ubuntuでの必須パッケージも載っています
このうち、 libsqlite3-dev が入っていないとそのエラーが発生します
Docker環境でわざとlibsqlite3-devだけをインストールしないようにして挙動を確認したところ、pyenv install 〜 した時点で警告が表示されました
root@2d51983c73b3:~# pyenv install 3.12.4
Downloading Python-3.12.4.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.4/Python-3.12.4.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.12.4...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.4/lib/python3.12/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.12.4/lib/python3.12/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'
WARNING: The Python sqlite3 extension was not compiled. Missing the SQLite3 lib?

pyenvをインストールした手順を見直すか、開示するかしましょう
必須パッケージが間違いなく入っているかの確認
必須パッケージを全て入れて再度pyenv install
あたりがやるべきことかと思います
